# How to add buttons in rasa chat bot integrating with telegram ui

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa

I want add the buttons in rasa chat bot for integrating with telegram but whenevr i add this buttion they are comming in one line only I want to it in for each line only one button and it should take the width of title of button. Also how to pass only button as parameter in utter_message function in rasa [This is code for buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FQrW.jpg) and
[This is output in telegram window where buttons title is not visible completly and also all they are in one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfuEO.jpg)

I tried to change the parametres of utter_message function but its not working

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74587972/edit). You can directly add the code as text in the question using the [Edit] button.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a typo in your code. You have set `"button_type":"verticle"` while it should be `"button_type":"vertical"`. Try changing that and see if it works.